# How to reproduce "Show in Folder" / "Find Target" via C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-shell

When using Chrome, if you download a file you can then choose an option (Show in Folder) which will open the containing directory and highlight the file.  Similarly, if you view the properties of a shortcut you can choose the "Find Target" button for that same functionality.  I have tried numerous searches, as well as looking over a decent portions of [the MSDN entry on Shell Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776426(VS.85).aspx), but to no avail.  I assume it's just a simple API call, or series thereof, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the very least, you can do that by invoking "explorer.exe /select,C:\path\to\file". I'm not sure if there is an equivalent API call.

[edit] Here's the [Microsoft KB article on Explorer command line switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)

Comment: Ya this is how it is done. "explorer.exe /open,C:\SomeFolder\Somefile.txt" to OPEN it. Also to open special folders like 'My Documents', 'Favorites' etc you need to specify their unique Ids

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that shows how to select files programmatically: [Windows Explorer wildcard selection shell extension](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/wildcardselect.aspx)